# populating a spinner with unique strings

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, spinner, unique

Im trying to populate a an action bar spinner with unique Strings based on the user input in a dialog box, eg user enters a string and if it's not already in the spinner, it should add itself there. Is such an implementation possible ? I tried using the ArrayList class but of course, duplicates are there, should I use hashset ? thanks

```
// array of sample strings to popluate dropdown list
ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

// create an array adapter to popluate dropdown list
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);

 //thats the alert dialog through which user enters strings
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("New category");
        alert.setMessage("Please enter a new category ");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        Editable value = input.getText();
                        // Do something with value!

                        categories.add(value.toString());

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest before adding to categories that you check if it's already been added before or not using ArrayList.contains:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Another thing to think about would be the case sensitivity, perhaps you could convert to lower case **before** checking if it already exists in the arraylist and only adding if it doesn't.